# Error 32, Python, file being used by another process

Tags: python

I have a simple program, which looks for all compressed folders in a directory, targets one compressed file, gets an excel file located inside the compressed file and moves it to another location (it does this for every excel file, for how many ever compressed folders):

```
path = 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Extract'
new_path = 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Test'
i = 0
for folder in os.listdir(path):
        path_to_folder = os.path.join(path, folder)

        zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path, folder))
        for name in zfile.namelist():
            if name.endswith('.xls'):
                new_name = str(i)+'_'+name
                new_path = os.path.join(new_path, new_name)
                zfile.close()
                #os.rename(path_to_folde, new_path) -- ERROR HERE
                shutil.move(path_to_folde, new_path) -- AND ERROR HERE
        i += 1
```

I have tried 2 ways to move the excel file `os.rename` and `shutil.move`. I keep on getting an error:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file beacause it is being used by another process.

I don't understand why this error persists, since I have closed every folder.

Comment: Find out what process is using it. Do you have it open in Excel?

Comment: I recommend you wrap the body of your `for` loop inside a `try`/`except` - you will want to close `zfile` no matter what. (I may of course be misunderstanding how the `zipfile` library works or the nature of that `WindowsError`.)

Comment: @Blender I don't have it open in Excel, I have closed every program except Python

Comment: @2rs2ts or, even better, using `with`

Comment: @J0HN oh yeah, I'm not used to that one since I just learned about it but if I understand correctly that'll take care of closing it automatically, right?

Comment: @2rs2ts yes, exactly. And it could do some more, google for it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
path = 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Extract'
destination_path = 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Test'
i = 0
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    path_to_zip_file = os.path.join(path, folder)

    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file)
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        if name.endswith('.xls'):
            new_name = str(i)+'_'+name
            new_path = os.path.join(destination_path, new_name)
            # This is obviously going to fail because we just opened it
            shutil.move(path_to_zip_file, new_path)
    i += 1
    zfile.close()
```

Changed some of the variable names in your code snippet. Do you see your problem now? You're trying to move the zip file that *your* process has open. You'll need to copy the `.xls` file to your destination using the zipfile module.

Comment: I'm using a function called `shutil.copy2(path_to_folder, new_path)`, this does move the file to a new location, but for some reason the file becomes corrupt.

Comment: That's because you are acting upon a file-like object that's been provided to you by the zipfile module. You've probably copied the compressed bytes. You're going to have to use this method at some point. http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.open

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a windows computer go to the task manager and hit the processes tab. Scroll down to anything that says python and end the process. You may have had python running with something else. Then try running your python program again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

downloaded files must be marked as 'unblock' in the properties window of the file
before they can be worked with code.